# Embed rendered gist in github page

Tags: google-visualization, github-pages

I want to embed a gist containing a Google Chart (rendered [here](https://cdn.rawgit.com/whanley/71bc1fac509a23b93a3a89b51af32bf8/raw/d98c33c8fbf5ee67a89395c0e435ac9568bcd0c1/dig-eg-gaz-issues-calendar-chart.html)) into this [github.io page](https://dig-eg-gaz.github.io/contents/).

I've tried

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/whanley/71bc1fac509a23b93a3a89b51af32bf8/raw/d98c33c8fbf5ee67a89395c0e435ac9568bcd0c1/dig-eg-gaz-issues-calendar-chart.html"></script>
```

and

```
<image src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/whanley/71bc1fac509a23b93a3a89b51af32bf8/raw/d98c33c8fbf5ee67a89395c0e435ac9568bcd0c1/dig-eg-gaz-issues-calendar-chart.html"></image>
```

and

```
{% gist 71bc1fac509a23b93a3a89b51af32bf8 %}
```

but these are not the right thing to do. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `script` or `image`, I need to use `iframe` in the code listed above. Works fine now.